# jQuery: dynamic HTML dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i use 1 div element to make the `.background` for my site. and it's will be 100% height. to achieve that i use jQuery dimensions utility.

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

with this script to get the height

```
$('.background').css( 'height', $(window).height() );
```

but now, i want to make it's height dynamic. if we resizing the browser. the height of `.background` will follow the new size of browser. i understand this will require some `event` since the size change after the page is first rendered.

can you please tell how to make it with jQuery?

Comment: Why use jQuery? Can't you use CSS: `.background {height: 100%;}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.background').css( 'height', $(window).height() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/resize/.

You'll have to add the same code above to the window's resize event.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using css fixed positioning? This lets you set the height, width and position of an element relative to the viewport (the browser window).

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp